# putting non trivial items in a multiset

Tags: c++, stl

I have this class (I am making a task scheduler). This represents the items that are queued up.

```
class QueueItem
{
    friend class TimerQueue;
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point when_;
    std::packaged_task<void(void)> what_;
    std::string name_;
public:
     bool operator<(const QueueItem& other)
    {
        return when_ > other.when_;
    }
};
using QueueItemP = std::shared_ptr<QueueItem>;
```

Normally I would never put something like this is a STL container, I would always used `shared_ptr<QI>`.
However I just discovered (duh) that my sort comparator ( the operator < ) doesnt work here. This is because multiset needs a '<' on `shared_ptr<QueueItem>` objects.

I don't know what to do, I presume there is no way that I can implement a '<' for `shared_ptr<QI>`. So I suppose I have to store the real objects in the container. But I feel like I am going to end up in the world of move, forward, && refs etc (which I don't get at all, maybe this is the time to learn) given that I have that `std::packaged_task` there (of which I am very wary of abusing)

What are my choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you implement a comparison operator on a `shared_ptr`?

(untested code)

```
struct Compare {
  bool operator ()(const QueueItemP &lhs, 
                   const QueueItemP &rhs) const
  { return *lhs < *rhs; }
};

std::multiset<QueueItemP, Compare> m;
```

Comment: because I had forgotten that I could pass a comparator to the constructor of multiset - ty

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, `std::set` use `std::less` as the default compare function. Usually `std::less` requires both sides of your `operator<` to be const reference, but your `operator<`'s LHS is not marked const, so `std::less` does not recognize it.

Comment: i dont understand how to make the LHS const

Comment: bool operator<(const QueueItem& other) const
    {
        return when_ > other.when_;
    }